# Comparing arrays with Painless

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Is there a quick way in Painless to compare the values of one array to another?  I'm trying to avoid a long loop statement.  I'm looking for something that will evaluate as the following two items:

```
ARRAY[1,4,3] contains ARRAY[3,1] = true
ARRAY[2,7] is contained by ARRAY[1,7,4,2,6] = true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve what you want:

```
Arrays.asList(biggerArray).containsAll(Arrays.asList(smallerArray))
```

In your case, both of the following statements will yield true:

```
Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,4,3}).containsAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{3,1}))
Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,7,4,2,6}).containsAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{2,7}))
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the set difference between the two lists? In the context of the above example, is there a way to get a list of elements that belong in the first list but not the second, and vice versa?

Comment: @Ned_the_Dolphin you can leverage the `removeAll()` method: `Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,7,4,2,6}).removeAll(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{2,7}))` leaves you with an array containing 1, 4 and 6
`